# Mimicing browser behavior

Tags: java, html, selenium, browser, dom-events

I am fetching htmldump of a web page. But I am not getting content which is loaded by Javascript at run time.

What is the best way to mimic browser's behavior and extract the htmldump which is exactly what we see on the browser.

We are using Java and people have used selenium earlier but it seems to have speed issue.

Comment: Define speed issue. You could try to use HtmlUnit directly, without selenium.

Comment: As far as I know, it was taking too much of time. I haven't used it personally so cannot give detailed description with confidence. Thanks for HtmlUnit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). It's a headless browser with javascript support, so it should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net, you can make use of the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control.

According to MSDN:

> Enables the user to navigate Web pages inside your form.

You can control it programmatically.

Comment: Sorry!! We are using java!!
Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can be pretty quick if you are happy to use firefox or chrome. There is also a way to run Selenium headless (not that I have done it) which could provide a speedy enough solution too. Otherwise there are posts and blogs ([eg.](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/02/speed-up-your-selenium-tests/)) out there that tackle increasing Seleniums performance speed. Another option would be to look at WatiN, though this is also in .Net just as seth flowers suggestion of WebBrowser.

Comment: any known issues with HtmlUnit suggested by others?

Comment: I have not used it, so cannot give any advice here. Sorry!